# webpage items change size when zoom in and out

Tags: html, css, zooming, positioning

My page, it keeps on getting different menu width when i zoom in and out. It is fine in IE, and no one else. I did not spot any fixed positioning, this seems to be using relative position.
have tried playing and disabling all CSS property to my menu bar through google chrome inspect element.
turn this from none to auto: " -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto "
Tried to use em ex px for my font-szie and padding. I am juiced out of ideas, save me internet!!!

www.magentek.com

Try zooming out, you will find press room gets pushed down. I got this SimplyBiz theme from wpcrunchy. It seems even the paid version have this problem too. The CSS and html is way too large to post, too much bloated codes, i think is sufficient to just use chrome inspect element.

Comment: Please read the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq . Questions are expected to include code, a detailed description of the problem so that anyone can tell what is wrong and hopefully what you have tried to fix it (as you did). A better description would be - I have a fixed width div that contains an unordered list of menu items. But when the user changes the zoom level of the browser one of the menu items wraps to the next line.

Comment: ok, yeah first time ask question. thanks for the feedback. Will apply next time post.

Comment: Lets kill this thread, is badly formatted as mrtsherman pointed out. Thanks for the help, will make better attempt next time.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the site, and my opinion is that the css and js that make up the menu functionality are creating a 6th menu element. That would explain why an extra little tab is hanging off the end there. Since it doesn't have any content, the browsers are all handling the whitespace a little differently.

Did you by any chance modify the menu to take it from 6 elements to 5?

Comment: mmm, i don't think there is a 6th menu item. that extra tab is just empty space with blue background(no tab). Just check it with inspect element tool, seems the menu element is correct. This is a wordpress theme called SimplyBiz. As we can see on their demo: http://wpcrunchy.com/demo/?wptheme=simplybiz